# UIScrollView's scrolling by dragging within a frame

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a parent UIScrollView containing a bunch of child UIScrollViews, every scrollview can scroll in every direction. On the top of each child, there is an UIView, subview of the parent.

I want to enable the parent scrolling only if the user is dragging from one of the upper UIView.

Any idea to do so ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can try to detect where the user is touching using touchesBegan: and if it is within one of the UIViews then you can disable scrolling (or even interaction) for all the child scrollViews. So in code:

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        //check if touch is in one of the UIViews

        //if so disable child UIScrollView interaction like so:
        childScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
```

Then in the touches ended method just reenable scrolling on the child scrollViews.

Comment: That is the kind of solution I'm looking for but unfortunately, touchesBegan: is not called when I scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have finally found something ! By overriding the callback `-(UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` of the parent scrollview.

`-(UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(myFrame, point))
{
    self.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
else
{
    self.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
```

}`